# Can I use a jquery string to target an id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, custom-data-attribute, targeting

I'm currently trying to build a menu, and I would like to have a dynamic targeting based on which button I'm pressing.

so for instance, my jquery code looks like this

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $('.nav-content').find('> .nav-links').addClass("hidden");
    $('#students').removeClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

but I was wondering if I could write something like

```
$('#'.'(this).attr(data-content)').addClass("hidden");
```

Here is a link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrg9f01u/) where the full contect of the code can be viewed

Comment: Please add all your code from the jsfiddle into this question for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

The right syntax to do it is

```
var currentId = $(this).attr('data-content');
$('#'+currentId).addClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation is done using [+ operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators) in JS. You're also missing a dollar sign in your `attr` invocation:

```
$('#' + $(this).attr("data-content")).addClass("hidden");
```

Compatibility permitting you could also use ES6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), enclosing your JS in `${}`:

```
$(`#${$(this).attr(data-content)}`).addClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of the code in your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrg9f01u/) with a solution: explanation in the comments in the js code.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
   var $nav = $('.nav-content'); // nav parent
      var targets = $nav.find('.nav-links') // links (targets)
      $("button").on("click", function() {
       var $button = $(this);
        var targetId = '#'+$button.data('content') // get the id of the target
        var $target = $nav.find(targetId); // find the target
        targets.addClass("hidden"); // hide all targets
        $target.removeClass("hidden"); // show target with the specific id
      });
    });
```

```css
.main-container {}

.nav-buttons {
  background-color: blue;
}

.nav-buttons button {}

.nav-content {
  background-color: red;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 70vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-1 {}

.content-2 {}

.content-3 {}

.shown {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-container">
  <div class="nav-buttons">
    <button data-content="home">Home</button>
    <button data-content="brands">Brands</button>
    <button data-content="students">Students</button>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-content">
    <div data-content="brands" id="brands" class="nav-links">
      <p>this is a brand</p>
      <p>this is a brand</p>
      <p>this is a brand</p>
      <p>this is a brand</p>
      <p>this is a brand</p>
    </div>
    <div data-content="students" id="students" class="nav-links hidden">
      <p>this is a student</p>
      <p>this is a student</p>
      <p>this is a student</p>
      <p>this is a student</p>
      <p>this is a student</p>
      <p>this is a student</p>
      <p>this is a student</p>
      <p>this is a student</p>
    </div>
    <div class="static-nav-links">
      <p>this link shall always be here</p>
      <p>this link shall always be here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```